# Java Observer on Map

Tags: java, hashmap, observable, sortedmap

I am working on something and I need an observer or listener that reacts when the EntrySet of a map changes.
I cant really tell why my observer is not reacting.

First of all I have a StorageModel that should be the Observable object:

```
        public class StorageModel extends Observable{

        public SortedMap<String, Integer> coMap;
        public SortedMap<String, Integer> co2Map;

        private String id;

        public StorageModel(String id) {
            this.id = id;
            coMap = new TreeMap<>(Collections.reverseOrder());
            co2Map = new TreeMap<>(Collections.reverseOrder());

            Observer storageObserver = new Classificator(coMap, co2Map);

            addObserver(storageObserver);
        }

    public void writeToCoMap(SortedMap<String, Integer> map, String str, int val){
        map.put(str, val);
        listenToChangesInCo(map);
    }

    public void writeToCo2Map(SortedMap<String, Integer> map, String str, int val){
        map.put(str, val);
        listenToChangesInCo2(map);
    }

    public void listenToChangesInCo(SortedMap<String, Integer> map){
        setChanged();
        this.coMap = map;
        notifyObservers(coMap.entrySet());
    }

    public void listenToChangesInCo2(SortedMap<String, Integer> map){
        setChanged();
        this.co2Map = map;
        notifyObservers(co2Map.entrySet());
    }

}


public class Classificator implements ConstantFields, Runnable, Observer{

static Set<MeasurementModel> classifiedWaspmotes = new HashSet<>();
static Set<StorageModel> waspmotes = new HashSet<>();
private static SortedMap<String, Integer> coMap = new TreeMap<>();
private static SortedMap<String, Integer> co2Map = new TreeMap<>();

private static StorageModel observerableStorageModel;

public Classificator(SortedMap<String, Integer> coMap, SortedMap<String, Integer> co2Map){
    this.coMap = coMap;
    this.co2Map = co2Map;
}

@Override
public void update(Observable observable, Object o) {
    observerableStorageModel = (StorageModel) observable;
    System.out.println("reacting to changes");
}
}
```

In another function that processes incoming data from a wireless module
I want to write the already processed data to the existing map and this is where the Observer should react.

```
public void truncateMessage(String msg, String nodeID, SortedMap<String, Integer> coMap, SortedMap<String, Integer> co2map) throws InterruptedException {
    StorageModel mod = new StorageModel();
    mod.setId(nodeID);

    String message = msg;
    List<Integer> coValues = new ArrayList<>();
    List<Integer> co2Values = new ArrayList<>();

    String idStr = message.substring(0, 3);
    String digits = "";

    if(idStr.equals("CO_")){
        System.out.println("co found");
        System.out.println(message);
        message = cleanseMessage(message);
        System.out.println(message);

        addValuesToList(coValues, message);
        System.out.println("values found in list");
        System.out.println(coValues);

        for(int i: coValues){
            //coMap.put(sdf.format(new Date()), i);
            mod.writeToCoMap(coMap, sdf.format(new Date()), i);
            Thread.sleep(100);
        }
}
```

I would really appreciate your help.

Cheers

Comment: ... and what is the problem? Tell us what output you expect to see, and what output you actually see.

Comment: The problem is that the observer is not reacting to changes so no output and when changes occur the observer should do some stuff with the data

Comment: Stick a breakpoint on your call to `mod.writeToCoMap(...)`, run it in a debugger, step into `writeToCoMap()`, step into `listenToChangesInCo()`, step into `notifyObservers()` and see what `Observable` does with it.

Comment: so the size of coMap changes but it wont step into notifyObservers(). is it possible that it does not add the observer as i want it to do in the StorageModel contructor?

Comment: when i override notifyObservers() it outputs my custom message but cant tell why the observer is not reacting to this

Comment: ok looks like i found the mistake.. it was due to Storagemodel not getting a id.